# Connecting tkinter input with a WHERE statement SQLite

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm working on a project for computer science, where I have to make a database program using SQLite3 with GUI (so I use tkinter)

Now I want to change the value of an item in a table with a WHERE statement, but this doesn't work. This is my code (I already connected with the database).

```
def show():
    Name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
    Name.grid(row=2, column=0)
    NameA = tk.Entry(self)
    NameA.grid(row=2, column=1)
    var1 = tk.IntVar()
    vijfprA = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Vijf procent", variable=var1)
    vijfprA.grid(row=4, column=1)

def veranderen():
    if var1.get() == 1:
        koe = NameA.get()
        c.execute('''UPDATE reserveringen SET deelbetaald = "Yes" WHERE 
        naamgezelschap = (?)''', (koe))
        conn.commit()

button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Invoegen", command=veranderen)
button2.grid(row=5, column=1)
```

This is only the part where the error starts. This is the error I get:

> > >
> >     sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.

Thanks!!

Comment: It's telling that whatever `koe` is, it has 8 values, but your SQL only allows for 1. Which of those values do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(koe)` is a single value, `(koe,)` is a tuple. The method `c.execute` requires a tuple:

```
c.execute('''UPDATE reserveringen SET deelbetaald = "Yes" WHERE 
    naamgezelschap = (?)''', (koe,))
```